# Issue with a paragraph pushing up between two floats

Tags: html, css

I've been practicing converting PSD templates to HTML/CSS websites but i'm having trouble with the navigation bar.

I want the logo on the left, and the navigation links on the right. So I've floated them to their respective sides. However the section below keeps pushing up into the middle of the two floats.

I've had a google but I can't work out if I need to clear my floats or if they've collapsed. I've also tried the `overflow: hidden` property, but it doesn't seem to change anything. I'd be grateful if anyone could shed some light.

Here is my HTML/CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/pL5gncu1/

Many thanks,
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place

```
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

between `<nav></nav>` and `<section></section>` and it will keep the section part below.

Comment: your welcome. and one suggestion if you don't mind... you have applied left margin to `<h1>Cuda</h1>` and right margin to `<nav></nav>`. Instead of this you can place them both inside a div and give margin to that one div. like here https://jsfiddle.net/pL5gncu1/1/

Comment: Great - thanks for the tip! Makes it a bit neater. A